# How to convert WPF GridViewColumn to checkbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to convert GridViewColumn to checkbox (bool) ?

```
 <ListView Name="MainTable" >
            <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Filename}" Width="140" Header="{lex:LocTextExtension Key=Name, Dict=Resources, Assembly=Mega.Player}" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsSuccess}" Width="60" Header="{lex:LocTextExtension Key=Success, Dict=Resources, Assembly=Mega.Player}" />
```

Comment: Could you stop posting code as images please? If you don't know how to format code read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Is `IsSuccess` a boolean type? I was under the impression it would do that for you.

Comment: @vcsjones: `DataGrids` do, `GridViews` don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `DisplayMemberBinding` and create a [`CellTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx) containing a bound `CheckBox`.